# How to get the primary key of an object after it is saved with DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Given this out of context snippet of my code:

```
var calibration = new Calibration
{
    CalibrationType = SelectedTest.TestTypeId
    ,Expiration = expirationDate
    ,LastSaved = DateTime.Now
    ,StatusTypeId = 1
    ,TechnicianId = SelectedTechnician.Id
    ,Phases = BuildCalibrationPhases()
};

db.Calibrations.Add(calibration);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a way with Entity Framework to get the primary key that was chosen(seeded) for the calibration object after `db.SaveChanges();` completes?

In other words how can I get the primary key for this object after it is committed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reload the entry in the context:

```
db.Entry(calibration).Reload();
```

Then you can access the newly created PK

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Don't forget to +1 my post if you thought it was well organized and direct.

Answer (score 2):

Also, You can get from `Calibration.PrimaryKeyProperty` after db.SaveChanges();

Means,

```
var calibration = new Calibration
{
    CalibrationType = SelectedTest.TestTypeId
    ,Expiration = expirationDate
    ,LastSaved = DateTime.Now
    ,StatusTypeId = 1
    ,TechnicianId = SelectedTechnician.Id
    ,Phases = BuildCalibrationPhases()
};

db.Calibrations.Add(calibration);
db.SaveChanges();



int value = Calibration.PrimaryKeyProperty;
```